# tabularx - How to linebreak in the tabularx environment?

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

How can I add a linebreak between two tabularx environments in a single section ?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx} % Nicer table style than the default
    \begin{document}
    \section{Research Experience}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\scshape}p{3cm}X}
    \textbf{HeadingLeft} & {\textbf{HEadingRight}}
    \end{tabularx}
    %%% HOW CAN I GIVE A LINEBREAK HERE ? %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\scshape}p{3cm}X}
    \textbf{HeadingLeft} & {\textbf{HEadingRight}} \\
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What document class are you using? When I try your example using `article` I get a line break. Do you want some additional space?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 14pt, oneside]{article} ... yes I need an additional space between the two tabularx tables. It makes it look organized.

Comment: Just use \mbox{}\medskip between the two environments, for instance.

Comment: Not directly related to your query, but still worth pointing out: the `article` document class does not act on the option `14pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a break between the two `tabularx` environments by replacing the line

```
%%% HOW CAN I GIVE A LINEBREAK HERE ? %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

with a blank line.

- Insert `\noindent` before the second `tabularx` environment to get it lined up properly relative to the first.
- To get a bit more vertical separation between the two environments, provide a command such as `\vspace{1cm}` (or whatever amount is right for you).